# Toggle not working on an element

Tags: jquery

I'm using

```
$("#termsLink").click(function(){
    $("termsWrap").toggle();
    alert();
});
```

to try and toggle an element that is set to `display: none;` by default. The `alert()` is triggered but the `display` doesn't set to `block`. I can't figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: You're missing `#` in the second line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be `$("#termsWrap").toggle();` not `$("termsWrap").toggle();`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you forgot the `#` hashtag before `termsWrap`